# Nginx regex redirect

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to create a custom redirect rule, but it's working at all.
Logs aren't helpful for me.

I'd like to configure 2 rules:

```
/api/appname/* => http://appname-edge:3000/appname/*
/appname/* => http://appname-ui:80/*
```

this is my try:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    # redirect /api/myApp => http://myApp-edge:3000/myApp/

    location ~* "^\/api\/(.*?)\/(.*)" {
        proxy_pass http://$1-edge:3000/$1/$2;
    }

    # redirect /myApp => http://myApp-ui:80/

    location ~* "^\/(.*?)\/(.*)" {
        proxy_pass http://$1-ui/$2;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
2017/03/30 16:32:25 [error] 13870#0: *1 no resolver defined to resolve app1-edge, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/app1/foo/bar HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2017/03/30 16:39:24 [warn] 14152#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/03/30 16:39:25 [warn] 14156#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/03/30 16:39:32 [warn] 14197#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/03/30 16:39:41 [error] 14199#0: *1 no resolver defined to resolve app1-edge, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/app1/foo/bar HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2017/03/30 16:42:22 [warn] 14321#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/03/30 16:42:24 [warn] 14325#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/03/30 16:42:32 [error] 14328#0: *1 no resolver defined to resolve app1-edge, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/app1/foo/bar HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2017/03/30 16:46:43 [emerg] 14628#0: host not found in resolver "$1-edge" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ims.conf:9
2017/03/30 16:46:52 [emerg] 14658#0: host not found in resolver "$1-edge" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ims.conf:8
2017/03/30 16:46:55 [error] 14328#0: *2 no resolver defined to resolve app1-edge, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/app1/foo/bar HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

In my test, everything should resolve to localhost. In the production server, DNS will take care about the apps name/DNS.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The log entries mean that your box cannot resolve `app1-edge` hostname. If you want localhost to server it, you need to edit system hosts file and add the following entry to it:

```
127.0.0.1 app1-edge
```

Then, I would change the regular expressions a bit:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    # redirect /api/myApp => http://myApp-edge:3000/myApp/

    location ~* ^/api/([^/]+)/(.+)$ {
        proxy_pass http://$1-edge:3000/$1/$2;
    }

    # redirect /myApp => http://myApp-ui:80/

    location ~* ^/([^/]+)/(.+)$ {
        proxy_pass http://$1-ui/$2;
    }
}
```

First, the regular expressions don't need quotes or escaping of slashes. Second, it is better to use the `+` for "one or more" match.

The assumption here is that the last part of the path contains at least one character in all cases, that is, there isn't an URL like `https://www.example.com/api/appname` or `https://www.example.com/api/appname/`.

If such URLs exist, the regex can be `^/api/([^/]+)(/.*)$` to take care of those cases.

You should also take care that you have only one `server` block in your configuration with `server_name localhost`. Otherwise nginx will use only one of those virtual hosts, which might not be this one.

I also removed the two `location` blocks in your original configuration, because you can have the same effect when defining `root` and `index` directives on the `server` level.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I'll try again soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having success with Nginx redirects by having this line in `nginx.conf`:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

And then a file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/redirects.conf` with a short stanza for each of the redirects:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name to-be-redirected.example.com
    return 301 https://example.com/its-redirected/sample.html
}
```

Then run `nginx -s reload`.

Comment: This seems to be a general redirect, it doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: It's a suggestion which is what is asked for above.  :-)
Some redirects like the above should work for the desired rules.